# SSL сертификат Let's Encrypt

Tags: битрикс, ssl, iphone, letsencrypt

Недавно получили на сайт бесплатный SSL сертификат от Let's Encrypt. Получали с помощью виртуальной машины VMBitrix 7.2. Начали тестировать на устройствах, в некоторых мобильных браузерах появлялось предупреждение о небезопасном сайте, а где то сайт не открывался вовсе (на iPhone не запускается, ошибка прикреплена). Есть ли варианты решения данной проблемы?

Прикладываю скриншот.

[image: Ошибка отображение сайта на iPhone]

Comment: Пользуюсь давно Lets и таких проблем не замечал ни разу. Иногда бывают проблемы с кешем, больше ничего.  Возможно - https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/net-err-cert-authority-invalid-error-on-my-website/55334  разговор там о том, что нужно использовать fullchain.pem, правильно настроить сервер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одна из возможных проблем, то что сервер неправильно настроен и не отдает промежуточный сертификат

```
# yoursite.com - ваш домен
echo | openssl s_client -connect yoursite.com:443 -servername yoursite.com 2>/dev/null | awk '/Certificate chain/,/---/'
```

Неправильный ответ

```
Certificate chain
0 s:/CN=yoursite.com
i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
---
```

Правильный ответ

```
 Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=yoursite.com
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
 1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
 ---
```

Решение в данном случае - нужно использовать `fullchain.pem` вместо `cert.pem`, пример для nginx:

```
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yoursite.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yoursite.com/privkey.pem;
```

- упоминание и [обсуждение(en) возможной проблемы](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/net-err-cert-authority-invalid-error-on-my-website/55334/3)
- [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html)
- Одно из обсуждение VM 7.2 [на форуме Битрикс](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum32/topic106857/)
- [Изменения обновления версий VM Битрикс](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=37&LESSON_ID=11219&LESSON_PATH=3908.8809.11219)
- [Данные о совместимости Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/)
- [Генератор SSL конфигурации (Mozilla)](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=nginx-1.10.3&openssl=1.0.1e&hsts=yes&profile=modern)
- [Интересный Gist c конфигурацией Nginx](https://gist.github.com/plentz/6737338)

Comment: Не понятно. Могу ли я попросить рассказать подробнее? Установка проходила через 3 действия. А тут я бы сказал сложно.

Comment: **это не установка, а проверка**. Вам нужно проверить в конфигурации веб-сервера какой подключаются `ssl_certificate` и если это `cert.pem`, попробовать заменить на `fullchain.pem`.

Comment: ОС - CentOS 7.2
Сервер - Apache.
Как я мог бы проверить не положив сайты на сервере?

Comment: это для информации https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum32/topic106857/ //  вы можете выполнить `ls -la /etc/nginx`

Comment: Я тут не вижу cert.pem и fullchain.pem. С чем это может быть связано? Какие есть возможные решения? Далее ответ сервера на указанный выше запрос: bx, certs, conf.d, fastcgi_params, koi-utf, koi-win, mime.types, mime.types.201701111402, 
mime.types.201807161154, mime.types.rpmnew, nginx.conf, nginx.conf.ori.201701111402, nginx.conf.ori.201807161154, openssl.cnf, scgi_params, ssl, uwsgi_params, win-utf.

Comment: обратите внимание пожалуйста в логе обновлений https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=37&LESSON_ID=11219&LESSON_PATH=3908.8809.11219 есть упоминание об исправлении работы с сертификатами, версия 7.3.x

Comment: настройки сайтов в `/etc/nginx/bx/site_enabled/...`  и `/etc/nginx/bx/conf/...`. Нужно убедиться в том, что подключается файл c цепочкой сертификатов, а не отдельный сертификат. Если трудно разобраться, то можно обратиться в поддержку Битрикс (при активной лицензии).

Comment: Изменения увидел. В техподдержку Битрикс написал, ответ пока не ясен. В директории по адресу /etc/nginx/bx/site_enabled/... есть файлы вида bx_ext_сайт.conf и bx_ext_ssl_сайт.conf, а так же сайты:  pool_manager.conf, push.conf, s1.conf, ssl.s1.conf. По второму пути лежит  1 файл и несколько директорий.

Comment: Хотел бы ещё уточнить, как Вы выделяете часть сообщения?

Comment: Стандартные настройки ssl - `/etc/nginx/bx/conf/ssl.conf`. Имена, которые были указаны, стандартные для Let'sEncrypt. В Битрикс они могут отличаться. Битрикс совсем недавно (этим летом) анонсировал поддержку Let's Encrypt.  p.s. К сожалению активно не используем VM от Битрикс, поэтому могу где-то ошибаться в деталях. Но думаю всё заработает и будет нормально.  // По форматированию  вот - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Ниже текст ответа технической поддержки Битрикс. `по результатам тестов, с цепочкой сертификата у вас на сайте всё в порядке. Значительных проблем даже нет, только со старыми системами.` Я не понимаю, в этом случае что-то можно сделать? Сертификатом Let's Encrypt я же не один пользуюсь.

Comment: можно проверить работу на простом сайте, certbot может  сам создавать конфигурации nginx, но это так для саморазвития.... **[Вот упоминания о совместимости](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/). Если совместимость есть, а  у вас она "не работает", то возможно проблемы в настройке сервера**.

Comment: возможно вы могли бы меня направить. Что именно мне нужно смотреть по настройкам сервера? и есть ли разница в туториалах к nginx и apache?

Comment: 1 -  посмотрите подробнее ошибку на устройстве (! что говориться в описании, например неправильный домен), 2 - убедитесь в том, что в конфигурации nginx параметр  `ssl_certificate` ссылается на файл, который включает два сертификата (основной и промежуточный). Если всё хорошо, то еще раз почитайте о совместимости/требованиях для конкретной версии браузера или ОС.  В виртуальной машине Битрикс **за сертификаты/frontend отвечает Nginx**. Nginx и  Apache конечно имеют разные настройки, но суть общая. Нам нужен nginx.